# Same pointer address but different fields

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I've been trying to learn C by myself after basic Java knowledge and I'm trying to implement a linked list. I'm running into trouble when making a createList function - a function that's supposed to make an empty list. I'm having a bit of a weird problem with passing pointers though. These are just snippets of the code, and my definitions of the node / list are located in a header file given by a book CD (so that's not the problem)

```
LList* createList(void){
    LList list;
    list.first = NULL;
    printf("List from mk_list: \nfirst:%d\nlist address:%d\n",list.first,&list);
    return &list;
} //This prints 0 and then the address of list

void print_list(LList *list){
    printf("\nList from print_List\nFirst%d\nAddress:%d\n", list->first,list);
} //This prints some random non-null address for some reason, but also the
//SAME address as the list from createList. Why does list->first not print as 0?

int main(void)
{
    LList*newList = createList();
    printf("\nList from main:\nFirst:%d\nAddress:%d\n", newList->first,newList);
    print_list(newList);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //Prints same exact thing as the printf in the createList.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return &list;
```

`list` resides on stack and its lifetime completes as function returns. So, using a pointer to it invokes undefined behavior.

Create the object on heap.

Comment: Thank you for responding! But if that is the case, then why is it that in my main function, newList->first still returns 0?

Comment: It can return anything. If you are unlucky, it will return exactly what you expected. It's undefined behavior :)

Comment: IntList* mk_list(void){
        IntList* list = malloc(sizeof(IntList));
        list->first = NULL;
        return list;
    }

this helped store on the heap!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your problem:**

```
LList* createList(void)
{
    LList list;
    ...
    return &list;
}
```

Variable `list` is allocated on the stack, whenever you enter the code of function `createList`.

Whenever this function (or any other function for that matter) is called, the stack is in a different status.

Sometimes it's 75% full, sometimes only 24% (this is just a figure of speech though).

Your local variable is allocated at the next free slot in the stack, so it doesn't have a constant address throughout the lifetime of your program, but only during the execution of the function itself.

Shorty after the function returns, some other local variable might be allocated in the same address.

Hence, there is no point in returning this address, as you are doing in your code.

### UPDATE:

One optional solution for you is to declare `LList newList` in `main`, and pass `&newList` to `createList` instead of returning a value from that function:

```
void createList(LList* list)
{
    list->first = NULL;
    printf("List from mk_list: \nfirst:%d\nlist address:0x%X\n",list->first,list);
}
```

P.S.: You should probably name this function `initList` instead.

Comment: Thank you, it seems you and Mahesh provided the same response. Unfortunately, I am still learning C and don't know how to make list store on stack rather than heap. Any advice as to how to fix this?

Comment: Added an optional solution for you